# Is this function always differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

I need some help with the following exercise:

Assume $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ is a compact set. Is the following function always differentiable?

$f: \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \quad f(x_0, ... x_n) := \sup\limits_{x \in A} \prod\limits_{j=0}^{n} (x-x_j)$

My idea was to show this directly for all partial derivatives:

$\lim\limits_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x_0,..,x_j+h,..,x_n)-f(x_0,...,x_n)}{h}= \lim\limits_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sup\limits_{x \in A}  ((x-x_j-h)\prod\limits_{i\in\{0,...,n\}\setminus\{j\}} (x-x_i))- \sup\limits_{x \in A} (\prod\limits_{i=0}^{n} (x-x_i))}{h}=\lim\limits_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sup\limits_{x \in A}  (\prod\limits_{i=0}^{n} (x-x_i)-h(\prod\limits_{i\in\{0,...,n\}\setminus\{j\}}(x-x_i))- \sup\limits_{x \in A} (\prod\limits_{i=0}^{n} (x-x_i))}{h}$

At this point I think it should be possible to show that this limit is finite in general or to search for a example for a non differential case should be easier. Can someone give me a hint how to proceed?

Comment: What happens if $n=1$ and $A$ has two points.

Comment: $f(x,y) = \max((1-x)(1-y), xy)$ can be written in this form but is not differentiable on the line $x+y=1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  Consider the situation where $A=[0,1]$. Is $g(x) = f(x,x) = \sup_{y\in A} (x-y)^2$ differentiable everywhere?

Answer (score 1):

Let's test the claim of differentiability with a simple example . . .

Let $n=1$, and let $A=\{-1,1\}$.

Then $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to R$ is given by
$$f(x,y)=\max\{(-1-x)(-1-y),(1-x)(1-y)\}$$
and since 
\begin{align*}
(-1-x)(-1-y)&=1+x+y+xy\\[4pt]
(1-x)(1-y)&=1-x-y+xy\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
it follows that
$$
f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
1+x+y+xy&&\text{if}\;x+y \ge 0\\[4pt]
1-x-y+xy&&\text{if}\;x+y < 0\\[4pt]
\end{cases}
$$
Now consider the question of whether the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$ exists at the point $(0,0)$.

First, letting $h$ approach $0$ from the right, we get
\begin{align*}
\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}
&=\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{(1+h)-1}{h}\\[4pt]
&=\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{h}{h}\\[4pt]
&=1\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Next, letting $h$ approach $0$ from the left, we get
\begin{align*}
\lim_{h\to0^-}\frac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}
&=\lim_{h\to0^-}\frac{(1-h)-1}{h}\\[4pt]
&=\lim_{h\to0^-}\frac{-h}{h}\\[4pt]
&=-1\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
It follows that $f_x(0,0)$ does not exist.

As a consequence, $f$ is not differentiable.